# How do I update XML?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to update my xml "ini file" using this code:

```
Sub WriteXML(strFilePathName As String, strNode As String, strNodeText As String)
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()

    xmlDoc.Load(strFilePathName)
    Dim MyXMLNode As XmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(strNode)
    MyXMLNode.InnerText = "stuff" 
    xmlDoc.Save(strFilePathName)
End Sub
```

The file date gets modified but the entry "ServerName" doesn't change.

Can someone suggest the code I need to tweak this xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Database.-->
<DatabaseValues>
  <ServerName>WS1</ServerName>
  <DatabaseName>LGRVPark</DatabaseName>
  <LastDatabaseServerChosen>Cellar</LastDatabaseServerChosen>
</DatabaseValues>
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking but if you are trying to create the xml this link will show you how to do so. https://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter-vbnet

Comment: @codeMonger123 : He's asking why opening an existing XML file and modifying the value of `<ServerName>` doesn't get reflected when he saves the file again.

Comment: Bruce, what is the full path to the file? Ensure you have write privileges to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XML Descendant Axis Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb384876) instead:

```
Dim x = XDocument.Load(strFilePathName)   ' Imports System.Xml.Linq
x...<DatabaseName>.Value = "stuff"        ' or x.Descendants("DatabaseName").Value = "stuff"
x.Save(strFilePathName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your time and suggestions.  This is what I created:

```
Public Function ReadXML(ByVal strFilePathName As String, ByVal strElement As String) As String
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    Dim e As New clsEncryption

    xmlDoc.Load(strFilePathName)


    For Each element As XmlElement In xmlDoc.DocumentElement
        If element.Name.Equals(strElement) Then
            Return e.DecryptString(EncryptionKey, element.FirstChild.InnerText)
        End If
    Next


End Function

Public Sub WriteXML(ByVal strFilePathName As String, ByVal strElement As String, ByVal strElementText As String)
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    Dim e As New clsEncryption

    xmlDoc.Load(strFilePathName)


    For Each element As XmlElement In xmlDoc.DocumentElement
        If element.Name.Equals(strElement) Then
            'element.InnerText = "inner text"  <-- This works too.
            element.FirstChild.InnerText = e.EncryptString(EncryptionKey, strElementText)
        End If
    Next

    xmlDoc.Save(strFilePathName)

End Sub
```